# Magento2: Customise product tab in view page

Tags: product, magento2.2

I want to display all tab contents in page load.

If I click the tab, then page scroll to the corresponding content.

How to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use javascript

Something like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41121797/10121426

> Assuming that your **href** attribute is linking to a **div** with the tag **id** with the same name (as usual), you can use this code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#goto" class="sliding-link">Link to div</a>

<div id="goto">I'm the div</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT - (Jquery)**

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $(".sliding-link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var aid = $(this).attr("href");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(aid).offset().top},'slow');
    });
});
```